# How to make table name dynamic in HiveQL script?

Tags: hive

I want to create a hiveQL script where first statement would be "Create Table...". This script would be used by different teams like Dev, QA etc, so I want to make table name dynamic i.e when script will run it will ask to insert table name and every team will provide specific table name.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hivevar` parameter for substituting table_name in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Set table name
TABLE_NAME=your_schema.your_table

#Or ask user to input table_name
echo "Please input table_name"
read TABLE_NAME

#call your script
hive -hivevar table_name="$TABLE_NAME" -f your_script.hql
```

And then in `your_script.hql` you can use variable:

```
CREATE TABLE ${hivevar:table_name};
```

Or simply call your hql script providing table_name as parameter:

```
hive -hivevar table_name="myschema.mytable" -f your_script.hql
```